# How to resist ab?

Tags: apache-2.4, ab

Is there any way to resist the apache benchmark tool on Debian? I have `fail2ban`, `psad`, and a bunch of apache modules that are supposed to defend against attacks,but `ab` on a different computer always seems to bring my VPS to a crawl. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rate limit the connections to httpd using your firewall.
- Improve the website code so that it uses less of the resources that are exhausted.
- Provide additional resources (gonna need a bigger VPS!)

All the usual stuff.